# To find the rank of a matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

I have 3 equations in the following  form $a_{00}x_1^{2}+a_{01}x_1x_2+a_0x_{2}^{2}=c$

i.e., equations in this form: $x^{T}Ax=c$.

For these kind of system, How the notion of **Rank** and **determinant** defined?

Comment: Rank of the matrix $A$ is defined as per usual. What you have is a quadratic form: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormRank.html

Comment: Thank you. And what about the determinant? is it same as resultant

Comment: Discriminant of the quadratic form is the determinant of the matrix $A$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom but my equations are defined in this way  $a_{00}x_1^{2}+a_{01}x_1x_2+a_{02}x_{2}^{2}=c1$    ,    $a_{10}x_1^{2}+a_{11}x_1x_2+a_{12}x_{2}^{2}=c2$,  ,and $a_{20}x_1^{2}+a_{21}x_1x_2+a_{22}x_{2}^{2}=c$